# Django - How do I annotate the count of multiple foreign key fields (within 1 model) to same model

Tags: django

I am trying to annotate the count of two foreign key fields, incorporation_country and acquired_country (both linked to Country model). The fields are within the same model (CustomerInformation). Below is my models.py for reference

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class CustomerInformation(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    incorporation_country = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name='customers_incorporation', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    acquired_country = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name='customers_acquired', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

What I would want to accomplish is to get CustomerInformation.objects.all() and from there, annotate to get the count of each country for incorporation_country and acquired_country. For example, I would want the output to be something like :

```
[{ 'country': 'Singapore', 'incorporated_count': 5, 'acquired_count': 3 },
 { 'country': 'Taiwan', 'incorporated_count': 4, 'acquired_count': 7 }]
```

So far I managed to do this

```
qs = CustomerInformation.objects.all().values('incorporation_country__country').annotate(inc_count=Count('incorporation_country')).annotate(acq_count=Count('acquired_country'))
```

Which has a major loophole as in the case where the eg. Japan appears a total of 2 times in the acquired_country field, but 0 times in the incorporation_country field, Japan would not be annotated as the values depend on incorporation_country. I tried adding both incorporation_country and acquired_country within the fields but the output was wrong.

All help is appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: The output is wrong because if you add two JOINs they act as a "multiplier" of each other, so the `Count` of one of the two, is multiplied by the other. Likely the count of the two was exactly the same?

Comment: The count of the two was not the same, the count was correct when I implemented that method, but the issue was that since I am using values('incorporation_country__country') before I annotated the count, it only takes into account the foreign key instances that appeared in the incorporation_country field (even if it appeared in the acquired_country field but did not appear in the incorporation_country field)

Comment: hold on. you annotate the `CustomerInformation` instead of the `Country`?

Comment: I edited the code to show the correct query already, sorry previously it was shown as qs instead of CustomerInformation.objects.all(). Yes, I annotated the CustomerInformation

Comment: but then a country that has no `CustomerInformation` will never appear in the list at all.

Comment: yes, that is the issue I am facing right now, would that be solved if I annotate the Country model instead? by using the related_name.

Comment: hello, I just tried annotating the Country model instead, and it worked! thank you so much :-) didnt think of doing it the other way around, haha thanks!